# Do I need to explicitly dispose SWT Shells?

Tags: java, swt

I have been told and have [read](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/swt-design-2.html) that SWT Objects must be explicitly disposed by calling their `dispose` method. However, in my own testing with the following code, I have noted that at least `Shell`s report themselves as disposed even though the dispose method is never called (nor appears) anywhere in my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


    public class Test {

        private static int numDisposals = 0;
        private static List<Shell> shells = new ArrayList<Shell>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display d = Display.getDefault();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Shell s = new Shell(d);
            shells.add(s);
            s.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            s.open();
            s.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {

                @Override
                public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent notUsed) {
                    numDisposals++;
                    printShellStatus();
                }
            });
        }
        while (numDisposals < 3) {
            while (!d.readAndDispatch()) {
                d.sleep();
            }
        }
        printShellStatus();
    }

    public static void printShellStatus() {
        System.out.println("Which shells are disposed?");
        for (Shell shell : shells) {
            if (shell.isDisposed()) {
                System.out.println("I am disposed.");
            } else if (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                System.out.println("I am NOT disposed.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So does Shell really need to be explicitly disposed? If so, how do you know when to dispose a Shell, and where should the dispose method appear?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [paper](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/swt-design-2.html) that you cite makes this clear:

> Widgets themselves do not usually need to be disposed
>   programmatically. A shell and its children are disposed when the user
>   closes its window.

So while a shell **does** need to be disposed, the burden is not on you to do so.  Nor do you need to call `dispose` on any of the children, as disposing a parent will do that for you.  Again, from the link you cite:

> When you dispose a Shell, its children are disposed.  In fact,
>   disposing any Composite will dispose all of the Composite's children.

However, you do have to make sure that you dispose resources you create that are **not** children.  For example: colors and fonts.  You do explicitly need to call their dispose method.  It's best to hook a dispose listener to the `Composite` you're using them in to do this.  For example:

```
public class MyComposite extends Composite
{
    private final Color color;

    public MyComposite(Composite parent, int style)
    {
        super(parent, style);

        color = new Color(getShell().getDisplay(), 255, 255, 255);

        addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e)
            {
                color.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It's important to note, however, that you should not dispose `Color`s that you **use** but do not **create**.  For example, do not dispose the system colors available from `Display#getSystemColor()`.